# i am facing an issue to get token using juno emr oauth1

Tags: amazon-emr, openstack-juno

am attempting to generate a token using Juno EMR OAuth1. I have added the client ID and client secret, but I encountered a status code "404" and an error message stating "no service found." I discussed the issue with the Oscar provider, and suggested them enabling the moduleName = Rest, but it said to me that is already be enabled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
this is the url
{{base_url}}/ws/oauth/initiate
this is the callback_url
{{base_url}}/index.jsp
{{client_id}}
{{client_secret}}
this also thing i added this in postman  authorization tab but still facing an issue gave me 404 error.